# Create one variable within another in SASS

Tags: for-loop, sass

I have a problem converting the obtained values into variables so that I can control the arrival data.

HTML:

```
$itemicon-ca: "\a100";
$itemicon-star: "\a101";
$itemicon-pin: "\a102";

$itemicon-collection: ('ca', 'star', 'pin');

@for $i from 0 to length($itemicon-collection) {

  $name: nth($itemicon-collection, $i+1);
  $value: itemicon-#{$name};

    .itemicon-#{$name} {
      &:before {
        content: #{$value};
      }
    }
}
```

Currently print this:

```
.itemicon-ca:before {
  content: itemicon-ca;
}

.itemicon-star:before {
  content: itemicon-star;
}

.itemicon-pin:before {
  content: itemicon-pin;
}
```

The idea is to convert the generated value into a variable, so you can print the data

I should print this:

```
.itemicon-ca {
  &:before {
    content: $itemicon-ca;
  }
}

.itemicon-star {
  &:before {
    content: $itemicon-star;
  }
}

.itemicon-pin {
  &:before {
    content: $itemicon-pin;
  }
}
```

Any ideas or suggestions to find a possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a variable dynamically in `SASS`. However, you can achieve what you want with a map and a `@each` loop:

```
$itemicon-collection: (
  'ca' : "\a100",
  'star' : "\a101",
  'pin' : "\a102"
);

@each $name, $value in $itemicon-collection {
  .itemicon-#{$name} {
    &:before {
      content: #{$value};
    }
  }
}
```

You can check [this](https://alligator.io/sass/each-loops/) for more info about `@each` loops.